# Magento 2 How to add custom field in customer_address_entity table? which will not use for front end or back end

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, eav, customer-address

I want to add one custom field in "customer_address_entity" table, for custom module. I have custom module installed. I am trying with "**InstallData**" script to add custom field. I do not want to show that field in front end or admin side.

below is my code

```
<?php

namespace Name\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

 private $eavSetupFactory;

  public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }


public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
         $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);       

         $eavSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'location_id', array(
            'type' => 'int',
            'input' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Location Id',            
            'global' => 1,
            'visible' => 0,
            'required' => 0,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'system'=>0,
            'visible_on_front' => 0,
        ));
        $eavSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address','location_id')
       //->setUsedInForms(array('adminhtml_customer_address','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'))
               ->save();
         $setup->endSetup();

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a field to `'customer_address_entity'` table you can make a `UpgradeSchema`, at `VendorName\ModuleName\Setup\UpgradeSchema.php:`

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $setup->startSetup();

            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('customer_address_entity'),
                'location_id',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    'length' => '11',
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => '0',
                    'comment' => 'Your Comment'
                ]
            );

            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
}
```

Change your module version in module.xml to 1.0.1 and run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: should i get value of 'location_id' from 'address_id" ?

Comment: For what you want to use location_id?

Comment: in location table i have 'email' configured there, with location_id i want to get that.